# NPM and Git Respository field missing but I have one in the package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

This is my NPM Package JSON, the Git Repository is defined in the json. It is a password protected on hosted at Kiln. But NPM still complains of a repository field missing ?

This is the error
npm WARN package.json dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 No repository field.

And this is the contents of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Pocket-to-Pocket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Card Management App For PFS",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://nyx.kilnhg.com/Code/Prepaid-Financial-Services/Group/Pocket-to-Pocket.git"
  },
  "author": "Nyx Digital",
  "license": "All Rights Reserved.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-imageoptim": "~1.2.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That warning is a dependency warning, and just means that the package dateformat for version 1.0.2-1.2.3 has no repository field. This doesn't affect your application, and it isn't an error, just a warning.

You can check this, as your application depends on Grunt, and Grunt depends on dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3. By checking the GitHub repository, you can see that the repository field for dateformat wasn't added until after version 1.2.3. The commit is [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat/commit/5511dbd927218fd266eff4c83f27ab931b957940).